# Typescript undefined constant during debugging session

Tags: node.js, typescript, webstorm

I have the following Node.js with Typescript [project](https://github.com/yudhistira-arya/typescript-webstorm-debug-issue) that runs absolutely fine. However, during debugging session, I noticed that exported constant from another Typescript file are always `undefined`:

[image]

I kinda suspect that this is due to the empty `names` array in the generated *source maps*:

```
{
  "version": 3,
  "file": "main.js",
  "sourceRoot": "",
  "sources": [
    "../src/main.ts"
  ],
  "names": [], // <---- empty
  "mappings": ...details omitted... 
}
```

Is there a way to generate proper *source map* from a Typescript compiler or maybe other solution to solve this debugging issue? Below are my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "commonjs",
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true, 
    "target": "es2017",
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "importHelpers": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "allowJs": true,
    "outDir": "dist",
    "baseUrl": ".",
    "typeRoots": [
      "./node_modules/@types"
    ],
    "types": [
      "node" 
    ],
    "paths": {
      "*": [
        "node_modules/*"
      ]
    }
  },
  "include": [
    "src/**/*"
  ]
}
```

I'm using Typescript 3.7.5.

The project was simply run through Webstorm's Node runner:

[image]

**Side note**: This issue didn't happen when I debug an Angular application that is run through `ng serve`. Not sure what `ng serve` do differently from standard `tsc`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, the empty `"names": []` in sourcemaps is the issue - `tsc` compiles your named import to `category_1.ANIMAL_TYPE`, and there are no name mappings, so the variable is undefined in debugger... You will face the same issue when debugging in VSCode, for example:

[image]

You can inspect the `category_1` object to see the values:

[image]

I'm not aware of any way to alter `tsc` behavior:(

Comment: Just found out that it's apparently a 4 years old issues that hasn't been resolved: https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9627